# Time complexity of BigInteger's nextProbablePrime()

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o, biginteger

What is the time complexity of [`nextProbablePrime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#nextProbablePrime--) method of `BigInteger`?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#l769), you see that there are 2 distinct branches:

- if the starting point is small, [Miller-Rabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) + [Lucas Lehmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) is used, with the probability of a false positive (for MillerRabin) under 2^-100. Candidates are increased by 2 in each loop, until a match is found.
- if it is large, a bit-sieve is used instead. The same primality test as above is used to test prime candidates.

For a big-O complexity, only the big case is important. Miller-Rabin requires O(k n^2 log n log log n) operations for k iterations (in this case, k=100) on n-digit numbers, compared with O(n^2 log n log log n) for Lucas-Lehmer (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test#Time_complexity)). Therefore, after ignoring constant factors (k), the big-O complexity of the **primality tests** that are run on each candidate is **O(n^2 log n log log n)**

The true time-complexity has to factor in the **gaps between primes** - if you have to run primality tests on a large number of primes (and the gaps [increase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) with starting-point), your complexity will certainly be affected. If testing a candidate has complexity C(n), and you have to test G(n) candidates, your complexity will be **G(n) * C(n)**. I could, at this point, look into the implementation of the [sieve](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/math/BitSieve.java) used in Java.

But there is an easier, correct answer to the original question of Big-Oh complexity: there is a [hard upper limit](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#l827) on the size of primes that Java will look at. Therefore, as there is a maximal n beyond which all calls to `n.nextProbablePrime()` launch an exception, **this method is O(1)**.

Comment: A small note that the comments in BigInteger are wrong -- it is the [Lucas test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test), not the [Lucas-Lehmer test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test).  The latter is only used for Mersenne numbers, so clearly makes no sense here.  The code itself is a non-strong Lucas test, so it's doing a weak version of the BPSW test.